# Why is this jquery .each loop stopping my function call in the middle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is the entire function I am working on:

```
function collapse(){
var i = 0;
var currColors = [];
var currTitles = [];
// Get the color and the course id of all the current courses
$('.course').each(function (){
    if (rgb2hex($(this).css("background-color")) !== "#f9f9f9") {
        currColors.push(rgb2hex($(this).css("background-color")));
        currTitles.push($(this).children(".course-id").text());
        $(this).children(".course-delete").remove();
        $(this).children(".course-id").text("");
        $(this).css('background', "#f9f9f9");
    }
});
alert("made it");
// Redistribute the classes
// This is where reverse lookup will eventually happen  
i = 0;
$('div.course').each(function (){
    if (i>=currTitles.length){
        return false;
    }
    $(this).children(".course-id").text(currTitles[i]);
    $(this).css('background', currColors[i++]);
    $(this).append("<button id='temp' class='course-delete'>X</button>");
});
var i = currColors.length-1;
};
```

And this is the problematic section

```
$('.course').each(function (){
    if (rgb2hex($(this).css("background-color")) !== "#f9f9f9") {
        currColors.push(rgb2hex($(this).css("background-color")));
        currTitles.push($(this).children(".course-id").text());
        $(this).children(".course-delete").remove();
        $(this).children(".course-id").text("");
        $(this).css('background', "#f9f9f9");
    }
});
```

I have this function collapse that is supposed to fill in the blank spot in a list of divs that the user has been adding to the screen if they delete one. This function was working fine at one point, but obviously I have screwed it up some how.

There are only and always will be 6 '.course' items because that is the size of the list. When collapse() is called it stops running after n times where n is the number of '.course' elements currently in use. The loop stops there and the whole function stops there. I have tried putting alert() statements everywhere but still no luck. If someone spots what I am missing I would really appreciate it.

I have figured out a work around for now, but I would like to know why my entire function is crashing in the middle.

Comment: may i know which `each`?

Comment: could you create a fiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: JSLint says: declaring var i twice and unnecessary semicolon at end of function. Try fixing these and see if it works. Seems to work without those corrections however: http://jsfiddle.net/xsD7y/

Comment: Don't you have an exception in your console ? What happens when you debug step by step ?